# How can I calculate all grouping permutations of an input string in SQL?

Tags: postgresql, query, recursive

Given an input like "ABC" generate a query that calculates all potential splits of 0 or more of the given string,

Desired output,

```
A   B   C
A   BC
AB  C
ABC
```

Given an input like "ABCD"

```
A    B   C    D
A    BC  D
A    B   CD
AB   C   D
A    BCD
AB   CD
ABC  D
ABCD
```

Not all that concerned with how output is formed, array, rows, json, etc. More looking for discrete list of all permutations of grouping.

Answer (score 9):

I guess that is just a challenge for fun, but here is my solution:

```
WITH s(s) AS (VALUES ('ABCD'))
SELECT substr(s, 1, 1) ||
       string_agg(
          CASE WHEN i & (2::numeric ^ p)::bigint = 0 THEN '' ELSE ' ' END ||
          substr(s, p + 2, 1),
          ''
       )
FROM s
   CROSS JOIN generate_series(0, (2::numeric ^ (length(s) - 1) - 1)::bigint) AS i
   CROSS JOIN generate_series(0, length(s) - 2) AS p
GROUP BY s, i;

 ?column? 
══════════
 A BC D
 AB C D
 ABCD
 ABC D
 A B CD
 AB CD
 A B C D
 A BCD
(8 rows)
```

The idea is to get the binary numbers from 0 to 2 ^ (length - 1) - 1 and interpolate spaces wherever there is a 1. So 101 (decimal 5) would become `A BC D`.

Answer (score 3):

The binomial problem can be translated to this simple pseudo-code algorithm:

```
take the first letter
while more letters, loop
   make two copies, one with trailing space
   append next letter
end loop
```

#### Recursive function

This can be implemented with a recursive function in any capable procedural language. Using PL/pgSQL.

##### Basic version

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION word_permutations(_word text)
  RETURNS SETOF text
  LANGUAGE plpgsql IMMUTABLE PARALLEL SAFE STRICT AS
$func$
BEGIN
   IF length(_word) > 1 THEN
      RETURN QUERY
      SELECT left(_word, 1) || s || w
      FROM  (VALUES (''), (' ')) sep(s)
           , word_permutations(right(_word, -1)) w;
   ELSE
      RETURN NEXT _word;
   END IF;
END
$func$;
```

Call:

```
SELECT word_permutations('ABCD');
```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/pZ9P-Lft) (with performance test)

Performs *much* faster than Laurenz' query, and still ~ 2-3x faster than my rCTE below, with or without function wrapper. And scales better.

##### Optimized version

After input from [ypercube](https://dba.stackexchange.com/users/993/ypercube%E1%B5%80%E1%B4%B9). More than twice as fast and scales better. Shortcuts leaves to reduce the number of recursive calls.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION word_permutations2(_word text)
  RETURNS SETOF text
  LANGUAGE plpgsql IMMUTABLE PARALLEL SAFE STRICT AS
$func$
DECLARE
   world_len int := length(_word);
BEGIN
   CASE world_len
   WHEN 2 THEN
      RETURN NEXT _word;
      RETURN NEXT OVERLAY(_word PLACING ' ' FROM 2 FOR 0);
   WHEN 1, 0 THEN  -- corner cases
      RETURN NEXT _word;
   ELSE
      RETURN QUERY
      SELECT wl || s || wr
      FROM  (VALUES (''), (' ')) sep(s)
           , word_permutations2(left(_word, world_len/2)) wl
           , word_permutations2(right(_word, -(world_len/2))) wr;
   END CASE;
END
$func$;
```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/_whp6ZpI) (with performance test)

#### Pure SQL with rCTE

Since this is dba.SE, a pure SQL solution with a recursive CTE:

```
WITH RECURSIVE
   val(w) AS (SELECT 'ABCD')      -- input
 , sep(s) AS (VALUES (''), (' '))
 , cte AS (
   SELECT LEFT(w, 1) AS perm, right(w, -1) AS rest FROM val
   UNION ALL
   SELECT perm || s || LEFT(rest, 1), right(rest, -1)
   FROM   cte, sep
   WHERE  rest <> ''
   )
SELECT perm FROM cte WHERE rest = '';
```

Same result for all:

| perm |
| --- |
| ABCD |
| A BCD |
| AB CD |
| A B CD |
| ABC D |
| A BC D |
| AB C D |
| A B C D |

Comment: Erwin, have a look at my variation/improvement on your recursive one. I think it performs slightly better consistently. Not sure why, maybe it does less function calls. Only tested it in dbfiddle.uk

Comment: @ypercubeᵀᴹ: Remarkable. I guess it's because your approach reduces the depth of the recursion. I added a version to test some more: *db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=aeb6cbcbbbbee6f29fc851bf7c889422)*

Answer (score 2):

An experiment/improvement on Erwin's recursive solution:

```
-- experiment 3
-- variation on Erwin's recursive function
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION word_permutations_yper(_word text)
  RETURNS SETOF text
  LANGUAGE plpgsql IMMUTABLE PARALLEL SAFE STRICT AS
$func$
  declare
    word_length int := length(_word);
BEGIN
   IF word_length > 1 THEN
      RETURN QUERY
      SELECT wl || s || wr
      FROM  (VALUES (''), (' ')) sep(s)
           , word_permutations(left(_word, word_length/2)) wl
           , word_permutations(right(_word, -(word_length/2))) wr;
   ELSE
      RETURN NEXT _word;
   END IF;
END
$func$;
```

Tested in: [dbfiddle.uk](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=96c7f50b007a833a0dcf6e436b142499)